# Why does the main form have different hashes from different threads?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

As far as I was aware, the main form (here I'll call it `Form1` as is default) of a .Net windows form application was a bit like a singleton.  It seems to be special in that you can access the instance from anywhere just by using `Form1`; even though you only have one form instance, you can access that without passing a variable around.

However, I was suprised to find, that if I use the TPL to make a number of tasks, and run them together, and each of them call `Form1.GetHashCode` they return different values.

Furthermore, if I place a public member object inside `mainform`, then set a value on one of its properties, that won't be reflected in the tasks.

What is going on here - it is as though there is a new instance for each task, but that can't be right?  That would take ton's of memory/initialisation surely, and also I can't **see** lots of forms.  I know I can't access controls from other threads, but this is just an integer.  What is happening?

**Example Code**

Just make a new project and stuff this into Form1 one, with a single button on that form.

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Public foo As New Test

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        foo.bar = 99
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ThisCouldBeAnywhere()
        Dim Task1 As New Task(AddressOf ThisCouldBeAnywhere)
        Dim Task2 As New Task(AddressOf ThisCouldBeAnywhere)
        Dim Task3 As New Task(AddressOf ThisCouldBeAnywhere)
        Task1.Start()
        Task2.Start()
        Task3.Start()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Test
    Public bar As Integer = 4
End Class

Public Module TestMod
    Public Sub ThisCouldBeAnywhere()
        MsgBox(Form1.GetHashCode & vbCrLf & Form1.foo.bar)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: The Form class is a vb.net disaster.  You can write Form1.GetHashCode() even though the GetHashCode() method requires an **object**.  Form1 is not an object name, it is a type name.  It still works, this goes back to ancient versions of VB that did not have classes yet.  Using "Form1" in a thread creates a *new* instance of the Form1 class.  Which of course has another hash code.

Comment: +1 for calling out this VB disaster ! What a nightmare this was (is still) !

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, so I'm guessing the correct solution is to either pass around the form object or to create a proper singleton?